# how to get only the first name of a list in alphabetical order?

Tags: c#

I have a list with students and want to get only the first student from the alphabet.

My following Code gives me all current students in alphabetical order, but I only want the first one.

```
for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(letter); 

    foreach (var studentName in _students) 
    {
        if (studentName)                   
        {
            Console.WriteLine(studentName.Lastname + " " + studentName.Firstname);                      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to include a couple of examples including the expected outcome and anything else missing for a [mcve].

Comment: What is the type of the list  `_students`? You are probably able to sort the list.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Seems to be a class with `Lastname` and `Firstname` properties, so a simple `OrderBy` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `_students` is a `List<String>`, this will return *the first one* in the sorted list.

```
student1 = _students.sort()[0]
```

---

If you want to sort by property `List<Student>` (Sort by FirstName):

```
List<Student> sortedList = _students.OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName).ToList();
```

Now ypu can get the first one by `_sortedList[0]`.

---

You don´t need alphabetical loop anymore.
This snippet will print **all** students in alphabetical order:

```
_students = _students.OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName).ToList();  // sorting and saving
_students.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName)); // printing each element
```

---

If you want the first Student for each letter you can filter like this:

```
_students.Where(s => searchList.Any(s=>s.StartsWith(letter)))[0];
```

Write this into your letter-loop and every first one gets returned. Be careful null or Exception can be thrown if there is no result for [0].

Comment: So on which position do I have to put this? Like in the loop?

Comment: You don´t need that alphabetical-loop anymore.
`_students = _students.OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName).ToList();` will bring them into a alphabetical order. So you just need to iterate through you list and print them.  You can use `Console.WriteLine(_students)` or this: `_students.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName));`

Comment: Thank you!! But now my program gives me all students and not only the first one.. ?

Comment: So you just need the first of each letter? What´s with other ones?
I will correct the answer. Thought you want to print them aplhabetical (all)

Comment: No just one student. The first one of the alphabet. My program is like "write 3 and the first student of the alphabet will show up".
When the user choose 1, then all the students show up. But this point I already have. Now I just need the first one from the alphabet :)

Comment: Use this to sort you list `List<Student> sortedList = _students.OrderBy(s=>s.FirstName).ToList();` like given in the anser and `_students[0]` will return the first student in the list. If the Name starting with A ist for example Adam. If the first one is Christoph it will return him.

Comment: stupid question, where do I have to put the `_students[0]`? because it don't give me any name right now ..

Comment: you just need to sort the list and put this where you want the first-result to be.

Comment: So right know it gives me the directory "Studentdirectory.Student" instead of a name.. and I've tried it with `_students[0]` and `sortedList[0]` :(

Comment: @Nathalie If you haven't overriden the Student object's ToString() method then it will print the object name. Alternatively you can just print `_students[0].LastName + " " + _students[0].FirstName`

Comment: yeah! I found my mistake.. It works! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @LenglBoy do you have ideas for getting the last student?

Comment: Of a specific letter or last in the sorted list? Last of sorted list is `_students[_students.Count - 1];`. Element at the last index and -1 because count is starting at 1 and list-index at 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to create a sorted enumerable:

```
var sortedStudents = _students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ThenBy(s => s.FirstName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

This will sort the students A-Z ignoring diacritics.

Then you can simply iterate through it to print all:

```
foreach (var student in sortedStudents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(student.LastName + " " + student.FirstName);
}
```

Or just take the first one:

```
var firstStudent = sortedStudents.FirstOrDefault(); // returns the first student or null.
```

And finally, all in one statement:

```
var firstStudent  = _students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ThenBy(s => s.FirstName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: A `ThenBy` would be slightly cleaner than concating `Lastname` and `Firstname`.

Comment: @john any ideas if I want to know the last student in my list?

Comment: With my method you can call `.LastOrDefault()` (instead of First) and it will return the last student object in the list (or null if the list is empty). With LenglBoy's solution, you can simply do: `_students[students.Count - 1]` to get the last student object.

Comment: @john ah! Thank you! :)